# difference of regular expression \b between java and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex, difference

1.In javascript(chrome's console)
tested:

```
/\w+\b/.test("test=");
```

output:
true

2.In java
tested:

```
String regEx = "\\w+\\b";  
String text = "test=";    
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);  
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
while(matcher.find()) { 
  System.out.println("matched"); 
};
```

output:

3.Is there any difference between the use of "\b" in java and javascript?

Comment: `\b` in regex is same for most of the languages except few (like SQL). You failed to create `Matcher` object.

Comment: And it is used for specifying word boundaries.. :)

Comment: And I checked your java code (with an instanoce of Matcher): it matches...

Comment: Can we assume one of those Pattern lines should be `Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);` ?

Comment: thanks a lot. It is my fault.

Answer (score 0):

But when change the "=" in test string to Chinese words, the difference between java/javascript seems appear.
for example:
in javascript:
`/\w+\b/.test("test中文");//true`
in java:

```
String regEx = "\\w+\\b";
text = "test中文"; 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text); 
while(matcher.find()) { 
  System.out.println("matched"); //never excuted
}
```